# Authenticated system on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth

I have app on Rails. My authentication sysem works fine, but:
1) always after authorization I go to THIS_path
2) if I'm not authenticated user, but got to, for example, /research page, after I throw to the authorization page and after I throw to the pm_root_path, not to reasearch_root_path.

Why? Why store_location method is not work?

My lib/authenticated_system.rb:

```
module AuthenticatedSystem
protected

def logged_in?
  !!current_user
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= login_from_session unless @current_user == false
  @current_user
end

def current_user=(new_user)
  session[:user_id] = new_user ? new_user.id : nil
  @current_user = new_user || false
end

def authorized?
  logged_in?
end


def login_required
  authorized? || access_denied
end

def access_denied
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      store_location
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end

def store_location
  session[:return_to] = request.request_uri
end

def redirect_back_or_default(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  session[:return_to] = nil
end

def self.included(base)
  base.send :helper_method, :current_user, :logged_in?
end

def login_from_session
  if session[:user_id]
    self.current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    self.current_user.last_logged_in = Time.now
    self.current_user.save
    self.current_user
  end
end
```

end

And my method in session_controller:

```
def open_id_authentication(domain=nil)
  domain = "" if domain.nil?
  complete_identity_url = IDENTITY_URL + domain
  authenticate_with_open_id(complete_identity_url, OPENID_OPTS) do |openid_result, identity_url, registration|
    if openid_result.successful?
      matches = /\/a\/(.*)\/o8/.match(params["openid.op_endpoint"])
      google_domain = matches[1] if matches[1]
      if valid_account?(google_domain)
        account = Account.find_by_google_domain(google_domain)
        session[:account_id] = account.id
        self.current_user = User.openid_registration(registration, identity_url, account.id)
      else
        flash[:error] = t('flash.session.domain_not_registered')
        redirect_to accounts_path
        return false
    end

        redirect_back_or_default(THIS_path)
    else
      flash[:error] = t('flash.open_id.authentication_failed')
      redirect_to accounts_path
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What is shown if you change your redirect_back_to_default to raise the session[:return_to]

```
def redirect_back_or_default(default)
  raise session[:return_to].inspect
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  session[:return_to] = nil
end
```

The code doesn't look strange to me. Have you verified that store_location is called?